# TelegramBot на Python не запускается

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Ошибок в кодеPycharm не выдаёт,в консоли тоже нет ошибок, но при вводе команды start в Теллеграм ничего не происходит. Бот создан с использованием TelegramBotAPI. Токен бота брал в @BotFather

```
import telebot
import config
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.Token)
 
 
@bot.message_handler(comands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open(r'static\ welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (''
                                       'Добро пожаловать ,{0.first_name}! \nЯ -\
     /<b>{1.first_name}<\b> ,бот,который поддержит людей.').format(message.from_user, bot.get_me((),
                                                                                                 parse_mode='html')
 
                                                                   @ bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Изачально так не было,но если я ставлю эту комманду в начало,то Pycharm выдаёт ошибку PEP 8: E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить что вы не использовали `bot.infinity_polling()` - эта строчка запускает бота. Так в таком виде код лучше не держать, в своем ответе показываю отформатированный вариант.

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.Token)
    
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать ,{0.first_name}! \nЯ -\/<b>{1.first_name}<\b> ,бот,который поддержит людей.').format( message.from_user,bot.get_me((), parse_mode="html"))

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Всё-равно не реагирует на start. Может переустановить TelegramBotAPI?

Comment: @BloodyGrab Обновил ответ. Дальше добавьте стикеры и думаю все будет ок

Comment: Не сработало. Исправленный код:https://pastebin.com/vZ5HYY4M Две ошибки: PEP 8: E501 line too long (194 > 120 characters) и  PEP 8: W605 invalid escape sequence '\/'. Обе в 11 строке

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем,починил я! Код:

```
import config
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.Token)
 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAEEhRFiX_JWeptNfHPbJw2weqLL1e-75AACDQADwDZPE6T54fTUeI1TJAQ")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать!Я бот,который поддержит \
людей.').format(message.from_user, bot.get_me((), parse_mode="html"))
 
 
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Max Watson,спасибо за помощь!